# Is it possible to Export Memory as Shared in WebAssembly?

Tags: javascript, webassembly, sharedarraybuffer

```
(module
  (memory (export "memory") 1)
  (data (i32.const 0) "Hello World!")
)
```

```js
fetch('hello.wasm')
  .then(response => response.arrayBuffer())
  .then(bytes => WebAssembly.instantiate(bytes))
  .then(result => {
    // Access the memory
    const memory = result.instance.exports.memory;
    const buffer = new Uint8Array(memory.buffer);

    // Use the memory
    const offset = 0; // Start offset
    const length = 13; // Length of the string to read
    const message = new TextDecoder().decode(buffer.slice(offset, offset + length));
    console.log(message); // This should print "Hello, World!"

    // Check if the memory is shared
    if (memory.buffer instanceof SharedArrayBuffer) {
      console.log("WebAssembly memory is shared.");
    } else {
      console.log("WebAssembly memory is not shared.");
    }
  })
  .catch(error => console.error(error));
```

Data type of "memory.buffer" is ArrayBuffer and therefore cannot be used as shared data in a worker. Is there a way to make the exported memory usable as shared?

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare it as shared:

```
(module
  (memory (export "memory") 1 1 shared)
  (data (i32.const 0) "Hello World!")
)
```

Comment: It didn't work without specifying the maximum value for memory(`(memory (export "memory") 1 1 shared)`). I wanted to set the memory flag to "shared" for the hello.wasm file using an ArrayBuffer(bytes). However, I don't know how to find the memory block within the ArrayBuffer. My goal is to achieve ShareArrayBuffer using only JavaScript

Comment: Ah yes, shared memories require setting a maximum, I edited the post. A shared memory is a different, incompatible memory type in Wasm, you cannot magically make it so from the outside. I don't know what you mean by "finding the memory block" – the ArrayBuffer _is_ the memory.

Answer (score 0):

When I change the flag to 0, it causes an error. That's why it works correctly only when I change the flags that are set to 1.

```js
  const code = (new TextEncoder()).encode('\x00\x61\x73\x6d\x01\x00\x00\x00\x05\x04\x01\x01\x01\x01\x07\x0a\x01\x06\x6d\x65\x6d\x6f\x72\x79\x02\x00\x0b\x12\x01\x00\x41\x00\x0b\x0c\x48\x65\x6c\x6c\x6f\x20\x57\x6f\x72\x6c\x64\x21\x00\x08\x04\x6e\x61\x6d\x65\x02\x01\x00');
async function runner(code) {
const result=await WebAssembly.instantiate(code)
  try{
    // Access the memory
    const memory = result.instance.exports.memory;
    const buffer = new Uint8Array(memory.buffer);

    // Use the memory
    const offset = 0; // Start offset
    const length = 13; // Length of the string to read
    const message = new TextDecoder().decode(buffer.slice(offset, offset + length));
    console.log(message); // This should print "Hello, World!"

    // Check if the memory is shared
    if (memory.buffer instanceof ArrayBuffer) {
       console.log(`WebAssembly memory is not shared.(${memory.buffer.constructor.name})`);
    } else {
     console.log(`WebAssembly memory is shared.(${memory.buffer.constructor.name})`);
    }
  }catch(error){ console.error(error)};
}
runner(code);
function decodeLEB128(bytes, offset) {
  let result = 0;
  let shift = 0;
  let byte;

  do {
    byte = bytes[offset];
    result |= (byte & 0x7f) << shift;
    shift += 7;
    offset++;
  } while (byte & 0x80);

  return [result, offset];
}

// Load or fetch the WebAssembly binary file
const buffer=code.buffer
  try{
    const buffer=code.buffer
    const view = new DataView(buffer);

    // Skip the header information (WASM_BINARY_MAGIC and WASM_BINARY_VERSION)
    let headerOffset = 8; // Skip the first 8 bytes (4 bytes MAGIC, 4 bytes VERSION)

    const sectionNames = {
      0: 'Custom',
      1: 'Type',
      2: 'Import',
      3: 'Function',
      4: 'Table',
      5: 'Memory',
      6: 'Global',
      7: 'Export',
      8: 'Start',
      9: 'Element',
      10: 'Code',
      11: 'Data',
    };

    const sectionInfo = {};
    const memories = [];

    // Iterate through the sections and collect information
    for (let i = headerOffset; i < buffer.byteLength;) {
      const sectionId = view.getUint8(i, true); // Read the Section ID
      i++;
      let sectionSize, sectionCount;
      let start;
      [sectionSize, i] = decodeLEB128(new Uint8Array(buffer), i);
      [sectionCount, start] = decodeLEB128(new Uint8Array(buffer), i); // Read the size encoded with LEB128

      const sectionName = sectionNames[sectionId];
      if (!sectionInfo[sectionId]) {
        sectionInfo[sectionId] = {
          start: i,
          size: sectionSize,
          count: sectionCount,
        };
      } else {
        sectionInfo[sectionId].size += sectionSize;
        sectionInfo[sectionId].count += sectionCount;
      }

      if (sectionId === 5) { // Memory Section
        for (let j = start; j < i + sectionSize;) {
          let flag = view.getUint8(j, true);
          if (flag === 1) {
            view.setUint8(j, 3);
            flag = 3;
          }
          j++;
          let initial;
          let maximum;

          if (flag === 0) {
            [initial, j] = decodeLEB128(new Uint8Array(buffer), j);
          } else if (flag === 1 || flag === 3) {
            [initial, j] = decodeLEB128(new Uint8Array(buffer), j);
            [maximum, j] = decodeLEB128(new Uint8Array(buffer), j);
          }

          memories.push({ flag, initial, maximum });
        }
      }

      // Skip other sections
      i += sectionSize;
    }

    // Write to the HTML document
    const resultContainer = document.getElementById('result-container');

    // Print in sorted order by the start value
    const sortedSectionInfo = Object.entries(sectionInfo).sort((a, b) => a[1].start - b[1].start);
    let html = "<h2>Sections:</h2><ul>";

    for (const [sectionId, section] of sortedSectionInfo) {
      const end = section.start + section.size;
      html += `<li>${sectionNames[sectionId]} start=0x${section.start.toString(16)} end=0x${end.toString(16)} (size=0x${section.size.toString(16)}) count: ${section.count}</li>`;
    }
    html += "</ul>";

    // Print the memories array
    html += "<h2>Memories:</h2><ul>";
    memories.forEach((memory, index) => {
      html += `<li>Memory ${index + 1}: Flag=${memory.flag}, Initial=${memory.initial}, Maximum=${memory.maximum}</li>`;
    });
    html += "</ul>";

    resultContainer.innerHTML = html;
runner(buffer);
  }catch(error) {
    const errorText = "Error: " + error.message;
    const errorElement = document.createElement('div');
    errorElement.textContent = errorText;
    document.body.appendChild(errorElement); // Add the error message to the HTML document
  };
```

```html
  <div id="result-container"></div>
```

Comment: It looks like you are trying to rewrite a Wasm module to modify its memory to be shared. That usually is a bad idea, since the code in the module is not prepared to deal with concurrent accesses to the memory, and will most likely be non-deterministically buggy under such circumstances.

Comment: What you mean is that the current code structure is not designed to work with shared memory, so if I were to implement it using shared memory, it might lead to errors. In this case, the only solution that comes to my mind is to write the bytes of ArrayBuffer into a SharedArrayBuffer and run it on the workers.